# How to show an AlertView with another AlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to show nested alertViews. Problem, which i am facing in nested alertViews is that when i click an "add" button of first alertView it shows the second alertView, in second alertView i have a textField and a "Save" button. I want to save data when i click on save button and then reload UITableViewData, which is already in the first alertView.

I am new in iphone, so please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your alert views with different `tag` property so that in delegate method you can easily differentiate which alert view is appeared on the screen.

For example :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Info" 
  message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];

[alert setTag: 1001]; // give different tag to different alert views
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Now in delegate method :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
   if (alertView.tag == 1001)
   {
      // do something
   }
   eles if (alertView.tag == 1002)
   {
   }

}
```

Hope it helps you..